# A transitional word/phrase for this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> Goodman, Jackson, and Fricker are non-contextualist. _______, the mainstream epistemology is contextualist.

What transitional word or phrase should be put in the blank?

The best I could come with is "on the other hand", but that is for opposite views.

Any suggestion?

Comment: While, the mainstream .....

Comment: @user240918 Is comma after while required?

Comment: @no, it is not.

Comment: This doesn't need to be a single sentence in the first place. Just make it two sentences. Or use a semicolon instead.

Comment: It's not a single sentence, but it should be. A comma after "non-contextualist, then "while," without a comma. Better,  the dependent clause should be first: "While mainstream . . ."

Comment: Maybe "in fact" or "indeed."  I'm not sure because I'm not familiar with these terms.  Could you provide a less esoteric example, and explain somehow what the desired expression should signify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***However***

> Goodman, Jackson, and Fricker are non-contextualist. ***However***,
>   the mainstream epistemology is contextualist.

The adverb "[however](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/however?s=t)" is the best-fitting word as it modifies the entire clause, conveying that the entire clause in someway contrasts or contradicts the information that the prior clause or sentence conveys.

Incidentally, "[on the other hand](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/on--the--other--hand?s=t)" *does* fit there.  You could aptly say "on the other hand" instead of "however" because Goodman, Jackson, and Fricker being non-contexualist is the opposite of the mainstream epistemology, which is contextualist.

Additional Notes:

Both "whereas" and "while" *cannot* be used as they are subordinating conjunctions.  Using those words to introduce the ensuing clause turns it into a subordinate clause, a subordinate clause without a main clause, thus a fragment rather than a complete sentence.

Also, were the second sentence instead a subordinate clause, meaning the period beforehand would be changed to a comma to make it part of the prior sentence, you would not follow it with a comma.  To be clear, were you to use either "whereas" or "while," the two sentences would have to be combined into one sentence: "Goodman, Jackson, and Fricker are non-contextualist, *whereas*/*while* the mainstream epistemology is contextualist."

Answer (score 0):

Try "[whereas](https://www.bing.com/search?q=whereas&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR)" (or just *but*, or *however*)

> in contrast or comparison with the fact that.
>
> *"you treat the matter lightly, whereas I myself was never more serious"*

Comment: "whereas" and "but" has the meaning of "contrast". But here we do not have "contrasting". It is just about where to find two opposition groups of views.

Comment: Don’t overthink it. Many words will do.

Comment: You can't start that sentence with "whereas."  "Whereas" isn't an adverb.  It's a subordinating conjunction.  Putting "whereas" at the head of that sentence makes it a fragment, a subordinate clause without a main clause.